# Control a double light switch (hallway light & ceiling fan) with remote device so I can cover the existing switch?

Tags: switch, walls, ceiling-fan, light

In my 45 yr old apartment I have a double light switch which controls the overhead hallway light and the dining room ceiling fan. Is there any remote device that will allow me to cover the switch plate and place a cabinet against this wall? I think I can carefully push the wiring box inside the wall, leaving it connected behind the cover.

Comment: Two smart switches, controlled remotely from another smart switch or a phone app or a transmitter that can be linked in or whatever.

Comment: I believe code requires any wiring box to be "accessible" so covering it with a cabinet may cause a problem with that. iirc some people have cut holes in the back of a wall cabinet to expose a pre-existing electrical box so it can be accessed simply by opening the cabinet door.

Comment: Ceiling fan's easy; get one with a remote. The hall way light though.... wired to the supply side of the new receiver, provided there's wires between the fan's box and the hall light? If there isn't, and as long as you don't care if the hallway light works, then yes with a new fan. Not that it's going to be fun to shove two extra connections up in there with the receiver.... If you're going to screw it to the wall then you have to cut access in the cabinet and put a blank cover plate.